# Gedächtnisstütze für der/das Teil

Tags: mnemonic

Since years, I'm always looking up when you use *Teil* als a masculine noun and when it's used as a neutral noun.  Is there any word combination, image, or phrase that would help us to remember the gender correspondence more easily?

I know that there are several differences between the two; any would do, but, of course, the more differences your phrase/image/sentence will cover, the better.

Answer (score 11):

There is a verse coined by he 1850s pedagogue Theodor Hemmweiler that has since been used to memorize the use of *der Teil / das Teil*:

> **Der** Teil ist auf **die** Menge stets bezogen,
>   **Das** Teil (**das** Stück, **das** Ding) wird einzeln nur gewogen.

I hope this helps you, as it has helped ten thousands of German students.

Note that for "*der Teil*" (which is "a partial quantity of something", the "**der**" constrasts with the "**die**" of "Menge" (quantity), whereas in the second line the neutral "**das**" of "das Teil" (which is a separate object; a thing that one can catch and carry away) corresponds with the neuter of "das Ding" and "das Stück" which can be seen as synonyms of "das Teil"; or short: where you can say "das Teil", you usually can also say "das Ding", "das Stück".

People playing with a jigsaw puzzle:

> "Wir sind fast fertig. Es fehlt nur dieses Teil (= dieses Stück) hier, und dieses Teil (= dieses Stück) dort."
>   --> **DAS** = SINGULARITY

Shopkeeper of a grocery market:

> "Gestern sind fünf Kisten Äpfel gekommen. Ein Teil (= eine bestimmte Menge davon) ist angeschlagen, die können wir nicht verkaufen. Aus diesem Teil (= dieser Menge) machen wir am besten Saft."
>  
>   --> **DER** = QUANTITY